# Way to differ TypeScript object type from class type

Tags: typescript, class, object, typeorm

Let's have class definition in typescript:

```
class User {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public toString(): string{
    return name + id;
  }
}
```

How to differ class from plain object in TypeScript?

```
const user1: User = new User();
const user2: User = {id: 1, name: 'John'};
```

Those both are valid in TypeScript, but `user1` is class instance and `user2` is object.

I am asking that because I am expiriencing problems with TypeORM package where I am mixing objects and entity instances and it is starting to be very messy and I am not always sure if I have class instance or object.

Comment: @DawoodValeed yu mean transforming object into class instance right? :D

Comment: Yup, it works fine since the object gets converted into a class instance :D

Answer (score 0):

Answering:

> How to differ class from plain object in TypeScript?

You can use instanceof to distinguish the two:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

For example, `user1 instanceof User` should be true but not for `user2`.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

> You can use `instanceof User` to check if its an instance of the class or not.

**Method 2:**

> I'm using [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) to handle such scenarios, convert the instance to a class using `plainToClass` method before sending data to the repository.